# Telebot InlineKeyboardButton how to hanlde switch_inline_query?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm trying to make a custom 'Share' button with telebot. Is there any option to handle InlineKeyboardButton with switch_inline_query parameter is set? I want to know in which chat/user the message was sent.

Answer (score 0):

I made 'share' button by deep link with unique 'start' parameter value.